# Qt5Multimedia not playing after compilation

Tags: audio, qt-creator, exe, qt5

Tell me please what may be wrong.

I wrote desktop app for playing sound using Qt5Multimedia.
While I compile app in QtCreator it's forks fine.
But if I start .exe file sound not playing.
If I try to play any sound I get this error: "The QMediaPlayer object does not have a valid service"

If I add Qt+=multimedia in .pro file I get this error:

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 800c0006
```

So I add in .pro file: Qt+=multimediawidgets and than it's work.

I also copy DLL to the .exe file directory:
Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
Qt5Multimedia.dll

Why app work if I run it in QtCreator and not work if I run it using .exe file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix this trouble.
May be problem was in linked dlls. I delete all dlls from run folder and put new dlls all from C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin folder. Now its work!